# Unable to connect to Linux git Repo from Windows machine

Tags: windows, ubuntu, git

So recently I've been trying to set up a Git server to manage personal projects and work. I created a bare Git repo on a spare laptop running Ubuntu and I installed Git Bash on my Windows machine. Right now I'm having some issues in actually being able to clone my Ubuntu git server to my Windows computer.

I used git remote add origin myserver@myserver-Dell-System:/home/myserver/CentralRepo.git but whenever I try to clone to my Windows machine, Git bash spits out this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myserver@myserver-Dell-System: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and repository exists.
```

I double checked my add to make sure the address of my Git server was correct and I assume Git bash for Windows comes with OpenSSH.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get my Windows machine to successfully clone from my server to itself? Thanks!

Comment: Does the myserver user have access to that location?

Comment: does myserver-Dell-System resolve to the ip address of the linux server? Because that's what ssh is complaining about (could not resolve hostname ...); another option is to try ssh with the ip address instead of the dns hostname.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in case it wasn't clear, I called `git remote add origin myserver@myserver-Dell-System:/home/myserver/CentralRepo.git` on my server system, not on my Windows machine. The myserver user should have access to the repo since that's where I made the repo. I tried using the IP of my server instead of the hostname but then there's an issue with it refusing connections with port 22. Pretty sure there is a way around it but I'm not sure of it yet.

Comment: Okay so a little update I managed to ssh into my Ubuntu server from my Windows machine. Turns out I had to type in `ssh myserver@serverIPaddress` instead of the hostname or the IP alone.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I managed to solve my own problem after getting a few ideas into my head. Big thanks to [naxto asenjo](https://serverfault.com/users/23722/natxo-asenjo) for providing me with the idea to connect via IP address.

The way I solved my issue was to simply type in ssh `myserver@serverIPaddress` instead of the hostname or the lone IP address.